# Finding $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3})$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3})$ this limit  according to wolframalpha is equal to $0$.

So this is my work thus far

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3})$ output is $\infty - \infty$ which is indeterminate form.

So next I basically but it on the same denominator: $\frac{1}{3}$ $((3x + 2x^3 - 2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}})$ and turned $2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ into something easier to work with $2\sqrt{x^2+1}+2x^{2}\sqrt{x^2+1}$

now the limit is $\frac{1}{3} \lim_{x \to \infty} ((3x + 2x^3-2\sqrt{x^2+1} -2x^{2}\sqrt{x^2+1})$ and this is where I am stuck to do next and lost.

Comment: can you solve it with Wolfram and ask Wolfram to tell you the rationale behind the solution?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sim -\,{1 \over 4x}$ as $\displaystyle x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

$$x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}=\frac{\left(x+\frac{2}{3}x^3\right)^2-\frac{4}{9}(x^2+1)^3}{x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3}+ \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}}=$$
$$=\frac{-\frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{4}{9}}{x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3}+ \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}}=\frac{-\frac{1}{3x}-\frac{4}{9x^3}}{\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{2}{3}+ \frac{2(1+\frac{1}{x^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}}\rightarrow0$$ for $x\rightarrow+\infty.$

Comment: question how you got first line?

Comment: @EM4 I used $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2,$ where $x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} =a$ and $\frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}=b$.

Comment: how you got the bottom of the first line by rationalized?

Comment: @EM4 I used $a-b=\frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{a+b}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$ and see my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

First, observe
$$3x+2x^3-2(x^2+1)^{3/2}=\frac{3x^2+4}{-3x-2x^3-2\sqrt{x^2+1}-2x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$
The top is a quadratic, while the bottom grows on the order of $x^3$, hence the limit as $x\to \infty$ is zero.

Comment: Haven't you just divided by $x^6$ in total? I believe to see that your numerator has been divided by $x^3$, and your denominator has been multiplied by $x^3$... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Zuy You're right, I went way too fast on this haha. Let me fix it! Sorry

Comment: @Zuy all done! Sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

By [binomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation)

$$(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}=(x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} = x^3+\frac32 x +O\left(\frac1{x}\right)\implies \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} = \frac{2x^{3}}{3}+x+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)$$

therefore

$$x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}=O\left(\frac1{x}\right)\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

WLOG $x=\tan y\implies y\to\dfrac\pi2$

$$\dfrac{3\tan y+2\tan^3y-2\sec^3y}3$$

$$=\dfrac{3\sin y\cos^2y+2\sin^3y-2}{3\cos^3y}$$

The numerator $$=3(1-\sin^2y)\sin y+2\sin^3y-2=\cdots=(1-\sin y)^2(2\sin y+1)$$

Finally use $$\dfrac{1-\sin y}{\cos y}=\dfrac{\cos y}{1+\sin y}$$

Comment: why is y -> $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @EM4, $$x\to\infty, y=\arctan x\to ?$$

Answer (score 1):

You should recall that $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$, since $(c-d)(c+d)=c^2-d^2$. This should help you simplify the expression with the square root.

Though I don't understand how you obtained what you wrote, from what I can see you should get:

$$ x+ \frac{2x^3}{3}-\frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}=x +\frac{2}{3}\Big( \frac{x^6-(x^2+1)^3}{x^3 +(x^2+1)^{ \frac{3}{2} } } \Big)=x+\frac{2}{3}\frac{-3x^4-3x^2-1}{x^3+(x^2+1)^{ \frac{3}{2} }}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$A=x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}=x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2x^3}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{3/2}$$ For the very last term, let $\frac{1}{x^2}=\epsilon$ and use the binomial expansion
$$(1+\epsilon)^{3/2}=1+\frac{3 \epsilon }{2}+\frac{3 \epsilon ^2}{8}+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ Replace $\epsilon$ by $\frac{1}{x^2}$ to make
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{3/2}=1+\frac{3}{2 x^2}+\frac{3}{8 x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$
$$A=x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}=x + \frac{2x^{3}}{3} - \frac{2x^3}{3}\left(1+\frac{3}{2 x^2}+\frac{3}{8 x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\right)$$
$$A=-\frac{1}{4 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

Comment: I need to learn Big O notation, why does it ends on 3...because of the numerator of exponent?

Comment: @EM4. It is the first term which is "neglected". Using more terms, we should have $$A=-\frac{1}{4 x}+\frac{1}{24 x^3}-\frac{1}{64
   x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^7}\right)$$